# How can I move a website without moving DNS?

Tags: web-hosting, dns

My homeowners association has a very ugly, 15+ year-old design, website that's hosted with a major hosting company. I've found a host that offers free site creation and hosting for HOAs, along with a deluxe plan that includes custom domain names. The free sites do not include custom domain names. I'm trying to figure out whether and/or how my HOA could create a far better looking free site while retaining is current name.

The free hosting company says that it's possible to create a free site but the HOA is on its own for the domain name. I don't know precisely how this could be done - where are the gotchas? [I once moved a website into Dreamhost, but that was 5 years ago and I really can't recall all that had to happen. Scenarios presented elsewhere on the web don't appear to cover this kind of situation.] What does it take to move the site while retaining the DNS?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the poster lacks the level of understanding a Webmaster would be expected to have, and has not provided sufficient details for us to give an answer other then one so generic as to be meaningless.

Comment: There are many moving parts to a website.   In addition to having a website, the web server needs to be appropriately set up (virtualhost and SSL cert), and the DNS needs to resolve the websites domain name to the correct IP address.  Unfortunately the DNS is broken down into many parts, Registrar, Nameservers, DNS records - and without knowing more about these we can't meaningfully help.      Also, if you are trying to take advantage of the free hosting but features requiring a custom plan you likely can't do that without more cost and complexity then buying the plan.

Comment: When you say "moving DNS" do mean "changing your DNS hosting by changing the NS records at your DNS registrar" or "changing your A and CNAME records at your DNS host to point to a new server"?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Sounds like I need to do more homework before asking the question. Close this one if you wish.